# Argumentoutofrangeexception except it is not? C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am really new to coding and I have run into my first problem...4 hours after looking at it and I realise I probably need some help.

The code is for 4 buttons, all of which have a very similar code (in fact almost identical except for the ID variable), yet 2 of them say 'argumentoutofrangeexception index' when loaded, despite the index being the same. (or so I think)

I have linked below the code for one of the not working buttons and one of the other buttons which does work + the test control:

NOT WORKING BUTTON

```
public class Answer3script : MonoBehaviour {
    List<string> thirdchoice = new List<string>() { "first choice", "second choice", "third choice", "fourth", "fifth"};
    public static string answerCorrect3 = "n";

    void Update () {
        if (Textcontrol.randQuestion > -1)
        {
            GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = thirdchoice[Textcontrol.randQuestion];
        }

        if (Textcontrol.correctAnswer[Textcontrol.randQuestion] == Textcontrol.buttonSelected)
        {
             answerCorrect3 = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

WORKING BUTTON

```
public class Answer2script : MonoBehaviour {
    List<string> secondchoice = new List<string>() { "first choice", "second choice", "third choice", "fourth choice", "fifth choice" };
    public static string answerCorrect2 = "n";

    void Update () {
        if (Textcontrol.randQuestion > -1)
        {
            GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = secondchoice[Textcontrol.randQuestion];
        } 

        if (Textcontrol.correctAnswer[Textcontrol.randQuestion] == Textcontrol.buttonSelected)
        {
            answerCorrect2 = "y";

            //   if (answerCorrect2 == "y")
            //  {
            //      image.color = Color.green;
            //  }
        }
    }
}
```

TEXT CONTROL:

```
public class Textcontrol : MonoBehaviour {
    List<string> questions = new List<string>() { "This is the first question", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };
    public static List<string> correctAnswer = new List<string>() { "Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4", "Answer4" };

     public static string buttonSelected;
     public static string choiceSelected = "n";
     public static int randQuestion=-1;

     void Update () {
         Image image  = GameObject.Find("Answer1").GetComponent<Image>();
         Image image2 = GameObject.Find("Answer2").GetComponent<Image>();
         Image image3 = GameObject.Find("Answer3").GetComponent<Image>();
         Image image4 = GameObject.Find("Answer4").GetComponent<Image>();

         if (randQuestion == -1)
         {
             randQuestion = Random.Range(0, 5);
         }

         if (randQuestion > -1)
         {
             GetComponent<Text>().text = questions[randQuestion];
         }

         if (choiceSelected == "y")
         {
             choiceSelected = "n";

             if (correctAnswer[randQuestion] == buttonSelected)
             {
                 Debug.Log("Correct!");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Apologies for the really badly formatted code, I couldn't get it to work!

Comment: In most IDEs there is a Feature called Auto-Format Code. Depending which IDE you are using you can format your code as follows:
Mono-Develop: `Edit->Format->Format Selection`
or in Visual Studio: `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F`

Comment: `(Textcontrol.correctAnswer[Textcontrol.randQuestion])` does not verify that `randQuestion > -1`.

Comment: So sorry for the code. Thank you for the suggested edit. And @Rotem how come it verified it for one of the buttons and not the other? Did I miss something out?

Comment: Possibly some of the buttons run Update before TextControl does and some after it? Dunno I don't use Unity. Which line is the exception on?

Comment: You should really look into arrays. It probably won't solve this question, but it's the much better alternative than having a variable for each image.

Comment: Additionally to what AustinWBryan mentions here you definitely also should avoid to use `GameObject.Find` in the `Update` method .. it is very "expensive". Better do this once in `Start()` or `Awake()` and save it in privtae variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race-condition here! The `Update` of `Answer3script`  might be called before the one of `Textcontrol` so `randQuestion` could still have the default value `-1`

#### Solution 1

Instead of the first `if` you could in both `Update()`s simply do

```
private void Update()
{
    // Check if Textcontrol values are set already
    if (Textcontrol.randQuestion < 0 || Textcontrol.correctAnswer.Count < Textcontrol.randQuestion + 1 || Textcontrol.correctAnswer[Textcontrol.randQuestion] == null ) return;

    // ....
}
```

so if the `Textcontrol` is not ready yet than nothing happens.

The second condition `|| Textcontrol.correctAnswer.Count < Textcontrol.randQuestion + 1` makes sure the element with the index you are trying to access exists in the list.

Be aware that `string` values can be `null`! Therefore, the third condition `|| Textcontrol.correctAnswer[Textcontrol.randQuestion] == null` makes sure the value at the index you access actually has a valid value. If you want to avoid empty string (`""`) as well, you caould also extend it to `|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textcontrol.correctAnswer[Textcontrol.randQuestion])`

---

#### Solution 2

(I would prefer Solution 1)

Go to `Edit`-> `Project Settings` -> `Script Execution Order`
[image]

Click on the `+` and add your two scripts `Answer2Script` and `Answer3Script`. You also can simply drag them (one by one onto the field). Without giving `Textcontrol` a certain execution time here it will be executed in the DefualtTime block. So just make sure your two scripts are **after** the `DefaultTime`. Than hit `Apply`. This makes sure your two scripts always are executed after the `Default Time` -> after `Textcontrol`.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! I guess that never really crossed my mind (the thing about updates). I will definitely try it out!

Comment: another slight problem....it says that the .length function does not exist?

Comment: Yeah sorry my fault: `Length` is for arrays. For `List` you have to use `Count` instead. I updated it in the amswer

Comment: Thank you so much!